# XSLT: How to peek nested element

Tags: xslt

That's my xml I need to apply an xslt:

```xml
<document>
  <component>
    <structuredBody>
      <component>
        <section>
          <identifier code="S001"/>
          <...>
        </section>
        
      </component>
    </structuredBody>
  </component>
</document>
```

As you can see, here there's a lot of nested structure I don't need.

What I'm only need is to peek `section` element where `section>identifier.code = "S001"`.

I'd like to peek my desired element without taking care of upper structure.

I'm using this xslt but it's not peeking my desired `section` element:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="//section[identifier/@code = 'S001']"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I'm getting:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Above example was a reduced effort to simplify my problem:

```xml
<document>
  <component>
    <structuredBody>
      <component>
        <section>
          <identifier code="S001"/>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>attribute1</td>
                <td>value1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>attribute2</td>
                <td>value2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>attribute3</td>
                <td>value3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </section>
        <section>
          <identifier code="S002"/>
          <table>
          ...
          </table>
        </section>
        
      </component>
    </structuredBody>
  </component>
</document>
```

What I really need is to get something like:

```xml
<person> <!-- -> section-->
  <attribute key="attribute1">value1</attribute>
  <attribute key="attribute2">value2</attribute>
  <attribute key="attribute3">value3</attribute>
</person>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The XPath expression `//section[indentifier/@code = 5001]` will select any `section` element for which the predicate `indentifier/@code = 5001` holds, irrespective of any ancestor structure.

Comment: I've tried your expression... nevertheless, it's not peeking my `section` element...

Comment: Maybe it was bad reading on my side, is the first character of the code the letter `S` or the digit `5`? Somehow I though code was a number, if it is a alphanumeric string use string quotes e.g. `//section[indentifier/@code = 'S001']`.

Comment: Other than that, as you use `value-of` but haven't shown any string contents of the `section`, it is hard to tell which content it has and you expect to be copied to the output.

Comment: What do you mean with "peek"? Copying it to the output?

Comment: I've added some aditional details on my post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//section[identifier/@code='S001']">
      <person>
        <xsl:for-each select="//td[1]">
          <attribute key="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="../td[2]"/></attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>   
      </person>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Remark: this is the solution to the edited post.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. I've just edited post. Could you provide some additional details about how to solve that?

Comment: For an answer according to the edited post, I will need some more time, but at this moment, I am about to have a meeting. You will have to wait a couple of hours. I am sorry.